# Typescript cordova interface throws reference error "ReferenceError: Cordova is not defined"

Tags: javascript, mapping, typescript

I have a very simple d.ts mapping like this:

```
interface CordovaClass {
    exec(success:Function, error:Function, ...rest:any[]);
}

declare var Cordova:CordovaClass;
```

I later reference it in NativeCordova.ts:

```
/// <reference path="../lib/cordova.d.ts" />
```

However, when I call the below in that same file:

```
Cordova.exec(success, error, tag, command, params);
```

The browser throws this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Cordova is not defined
```

Fairly new to mappings, but from what I can tell from other mappings (like jquery.d.ts) this should be working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

**Update**

I was able to get this working by declaring the var with a lowercase 'C':

```
declare var cordova:CordovaClass;
```

And then calling it that way:

```
cordova.exec(success, error, tag, command, params);
```

This is because that's the variable used by cordova to reference itself, much like the jQuery d.ts did.

*exec is not a real call you can make with Cordova, but that's not the problem I was having.

Comment: worth mentioning you can get phonegap type definitions here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/phonegap/phonegap.d.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript definition file is just to tell the compiler about what's supposed to already be there. At runtime, you need to have the Cordova implementation present through whatever script loading mechanism exists for your host (e.g. in a browser, a `<script>` tag).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I did have the script included, but that understanding led me to realize that cordova should not be capitalized since I'm declaring the var that cordova uses as a reference to itself.